# How to reference multiple foreign keys in a table that is a primary key and candidate keys?

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON(  
    passportNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
    firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    lastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,  
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY(passportNumber),  
    CONSTRAINT person_ckey1 UNIQUE(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth)
);

CREATE TABLE CHEF(  
    culinaryCerts VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,  
    competitionEXpr VARCHAR(300) NULL,  
    passportNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
    firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    lastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT chef_pkey PRIMARY KEY(passportNumber),  
    CONSTRAINT chef_ckey1 UNIQUE(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth),  
    CONSTRAINT chef_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY(passportNumber)
                        REFERENCES PERSON(passportNumber)ON DELETE CASCADE,  
    CONSTRAINT chef_fkey2 FOREIGN KEY(firstName)
                        REFERENCES PERSON(firstName)ON DELETE CASCADE,  
    CONSTRAINT chef_fkey3 FOREIGN KEY(lastName)
                        REFERENCES PERSON(lastName)ON DELETE CASCADE,  
    CONSTRAINT chef_fkey4 FOREIGN KEY(dateOfBirth)
                        REFERENCES PERSON(dateOfBirth)ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

however, when I run the code, it shows:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'chef_fkey3' in the referenced table 'PERSON'

Comment: Why on earth do you need passport number, first and last name and DOB in the Chef table? Surely a Chef is a person so all you need is a link between the 2 so you can find a Culinary Cert and Competition Expr for the person that is a chef

Comment: `PassportNumber` is a really bad idea as a primary key. Firstly, it means that you are completely limited to who you can store. Not everyone even has a passport number, let alone would willing hand over that information. This is sensitive data as well, so you should be encrypting this in case of any kind of breach, as a primary key, this would mean you would also have to encrypt this in all child tables. A further reason is that if you have any front end on this, your unique identify exposed to the front end is going to be the passport number. Something you shouldn't expose; encrypted or not.

Comment: I'd be inclined to just add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and use this is a surrogate key, then link from person to Chef using this. If you need to store passport number, then store it once against Person, and encrypt it. You can add a Unique constraint to this to ensure a passport number is unique in the table.

Comment: In addition one should take into account that a person has more than one passport over time, in some cases even at the same time (temporary emergency passports, multiple citizenships). There should be a 1:n relation between PERSON and a PASSPORT table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `firstName`, `lastName` and `dateOfBirth` attributes in your `CHEF` table since you can retrieve them in `PERSON` with the `passportNumber` foreign key in a simple join.

You also do not need to specify `NOT NULL` when attributes are primary/foreign keys or if there are members of a unique constraint.

You can simplify your script like this :

```sql
CREATE TABLE PERSON (  
    passportNumber VARCHAR(20),  
    firstName VARCHAR(30),
    lastName VARCHAR(30),
    dateOfBirth DATE,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY (passportNumber),
    CONSTRAINT person_ckey1 UNIQUE(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth)
);

CREATE TABLE CHEF (
    culinaryCerts VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    competitionEXpr VARCHAR(300),
    passportNumber VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT chef_pk PRIMARY KEY (passportNumber),
    CONSTRAINT chef_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (passportNumber) REFERENCES PERSON(passportNumber)
);
```

then retrieve your data like this :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM PERSON AS p
INNER JOIN CHEF AS c
ON p.passportNumber = c.passportNumber
```

Comment: I think this is missing the primary key on `PERSON (passportNumber)`

Comment: @GarethD I declared the primary/foreign keys next to the concerned attributes

Comment: Ah ok. I missed that. Sorry. I'd be inclined to still explicitly name them though (to match what the OP has done, and also because it is good practice).

Comment: @GarethD thanks, I updated my response

Comment: "You don't need the firstName, lastName and dateOfBirth attributes in your CHEF table since you can retrieve them in PERSON". This is correct in most cases, but not always. Names can change over time (marriage, etc.), so it depends on the problem domain if it is important to record firstName and lastName at that specific point of time.

Comment: @lukas.j so you should rather declare dedicated table(s) to keep history of names. It would be weird to have different names for a same passportNumber... It's not the job of the Chef table to keep record of a name

Comment: Of course that is also a possibility, albeit a more complicated one. It really depends on what the CHEF table needs to track (meaning if it needs a snapshot of the passwort data at that moment and then freezes the record – like with an invoice).

Comment: @lukas.j If that was the case though (i.e. freezing the record), you definitely wouldn't want the foreign key on these 3 columns anyway, as it would prevent this exact scenario. I agree with Alexis here, if changing names is a concern, then this should be dealt with in a person history table that tracks name changes, and any other changes that might happen (e.g. Passport number as you have already pointed out) rather than conflating chef specific information with change tracking. What if someone changed name twice? You'd end up duplicating Chef specific data to capture the two changes.

Comment: I do not disagree with you, but I also do not agree – IMHO it depends on the problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

You have a combined unique constraint on `firstName , lastName , dateOfBirth` so your foreign key needs to include all columns like you see in the example below.

But f you need all three separate, you need to define each column also separately in Persons table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PERSON (
>     passportNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>     firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     lastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
>     gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
>     CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (passportNumber),
>     CONSTRAINT person_ckey1 UNIQUE (firstName , lastName , dateOfBirth)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE CHEF (
>     culinaryCerts VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
>     competitionEXpr VARCHAR(300) NULL,
>     passportNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>     firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     lastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
>     CONSTRAINT chef_pkey PRIMARY KEY (passportNumber),
>     CONSTRAINT chef_ckey1 UNIQUE (firstName , lastName , dateOfBirth),
>     CONSTRAINT chef_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY (passportNumber)
>         REFERENCES PERSON (passportNumber)
>         ON DELETE CASCADE,
>     CONSTRAINT chef_fkey2 FOREIGN KEY (firstName , lastName , dateOfBirth)
>         REFERENCES PERSON (firstName , lastName , dateOfBirth)
>         ON DELETE CASCADE
> );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ac54ae94b4e7a9ef410a8da8ea0ac7e)*